# Sorting column fields of mixed strings and numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort my columns based on 'Value' field which is combination of strings and numerical values in the following order

```
var ascending = ["","","", 0, 0, 0.71, 1]

var descending = [1, 0.71,0,0,"","",""]
```

I tried the below sorting algorithm, but it is not giving desired results

```
function mySort(v1,v2) {
var v1 = obj1[colName];
            var v2 = obj2[colName];

            if(v1 === ""){
              return 1;
            }
            else if(v2 === ""){
              return -1;
            }
            else if(v1 === v2){
              return 0;
            }
            else if(!sortObj.descending) {
              return v1 < v2 ? -1 : 1;
            }
            else if(sortObj.descending) {
              return v1 < v2 ? 1 : -1;
            }
}
```

Above sorting algorithm always keeps the `""` at bottom, which is not desired in my case. What I am missing?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the quotes, or is it ok if those values are coerced to a Number (`0`)? Because `["", "", 0, "", 1, 0.71, 0].map(Number).sort()` works fine

Comment: yes, empty strings are to be preserved and different from zeros. That's where the default sort i tried first is getting confused and not producing desired order

Comment: Make the return value of your `""` comparisons dependant on the `sortObj.descending`, as in `return sortObj.descending ? 1 : -1`, and the opposite for the second `""`.

Comment: @squint - Making the return value of your "" comparisons dependant on the sortObj.descending worked with my above code. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["", "", 0, "", 1, 0.71, 0];
var asc = arr.slice().sort();
var desc = asc.slice().reverse();
```

The [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

The [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.

The [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method reverses an array in place.

Comment: Hi it works if my input is just an array. I am trying to perform sort on column fields, in which case this will not work

Comment: An answer the has only peace of code is not a good answer. Add some explanation/links to sources...

Comment: @nikitha, what do you mean by "columns"? There is no "column" definition in javascript. Please explain.

Comment: This sorts everything as strings, so it'll fail to give the expected order in some cases.

Comment: @squint - What cases would fail?

Comment: A lexical sort will put `"2"` ahead of `"10"`, for example.

Comment: @Dekel - Links and descriptions added.

Comment: Good call @squint

Comment: Much better :) got my vote here. However - note that it currently not the answer the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort first by empty strings, then the numbers.

```js
var arr = ["", "", 0, "", 1, 0.71, 0, 10, 20, 2];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a !== "") - (b !== "") || (a || 0) - (b || 0);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove those IF statements from your function.

```
    if(v1 === ""){
      return 1;
    }
    else if(v2 === ""){
      return -1;
    }
```

Numbers and strings like this are already comparable in JS.

Edit:

To compare 0 you can try this in the beginning of the function:

```
if(v1 === 0)
    v1 = v1.toString();
if(v2 === 0)
    v2 = v2.toString();
// the rest of your logic here
```

You can extract it to a method too, so you do not repeat code.

Comment: But, how does it compare "" and zeros?

Comment: @nikitha: They're numerically equal, so you won't be guaranteed to have all the strings grouped together.

Comment: Is there a way this to have this strings grouped. I am unable to achieve with my sort function

Comment: @nikitha check my edit, and you will be able to overcome this impediment.